# Estimate geometric transform in Opencv c++

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Actually I want to use "estimated Geometric transform" matlab's function in opencv c++, is their any kind of such function which works exactly same in opencv in c++?

[Matlab function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/estimategeometrictransform.html)

***Note***: I am using this function for creating bounding box around pair of eye on the basis of features, which are not static in every frame...

Comment: Check how one can compute a homography or whatever specific geometric transform you need. SVD is generally your friend. This is a common problem, tehre is alot of code around

Comment: which version of matlab's "estimated geometric transform" do you need? 'similarity', 'affine', or 'projective'? OpenCV uses different functions for each of them. Be aware, that (even in matlab) these functions might be randomized, so maybe you won't achieve the same results on each function call.

Comment: thanks @Micka I need similarity transform, could you please tell me that function in opencv??

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri :)

Comment: cv::estimateRigidTrabsform with the flags to not use full-affine. But you'd better code your own RANSAC around that.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you are trying to get is an **affine transformation matrix** from image1 to image2. 
Given the coordinates of a matched set of points in image1 and image2, you can get the affine transformation matrix using [estimateRigidTransform](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#estimaterigidtransform): as the docs point out, this function can be used giving as input two sets of pre-calculated matched points, **or even directly giving as input two images**: the function will internally find features that match in both images and will use those matched points to get the **optimal affine transform matrix**.

**As the user Micka correctly suggested in the comments to your question, since you got features that can be translated, rotated but also scaled, you need to set the flag `fullAffine` to `false`.**

Since you are talking about frames I suppose you are trying to match points in a visual flow, so this is surely the function you need. 
The same can be obtained images which could also have shearing with `getAffineTransform`: given a set of points in two images, this opencv function will return a 2x3 affine transformation matrix. To understand better what is an affine transform (and thus understand better the similarity transform, in you case) you can refer to the following docs. They are quite the same, just two versions for the two current OpenCV branches.

I prefer the layout of the 2.4 documentation, but the explained concepts are absolutely the same.

OpenCV 2.4:

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

OpenCV 3.2:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga8f6d378f9f8eebb5cb55cd3ae295a999